# The Dirac identity $\int \delta(f(x))g(x)dx$ on a finite interval

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

I know the Dirac identity
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(f(x))g(x)dx = \sum_{i}\frac{g(x_{i})}{|f'(x_{i})|}$$
where the $x_{i}$'s are the zeros of $f$ for which $f'(x_{i})\neq 0$. My question is: what if the integral is $\int_{a}^{b}$ instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ ? Do we take only the zeros of $f$ that are on $[a,b]$ ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Yes that interpretation is consistent. Just to be more precise, the zeros of $f$ where $f'=0$ aren't ignored. If those exist, then $\delta(f)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But if $\delta (f)$ is not defined at those common zeros, does it mean that this formula is false if for example $f$ and $f'$ have the same zeros ?

Comment: It's not just that $\delta(f)$ is not defined at those zeros, it means that $\delta(f)$ is not defined at all, anywhere. That's why restricting the integration to $[a,b]$ finite increases the number of functions you can insert inside the delta.

Comment: I see yes, thank's!